# Is $S=\{\overline{0},\overline{5},\overline{10}\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ isomorphic to$\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ as rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

My book asked me to prove that it is in fact. I generated the tables for addition

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
+ & 0 & 5 & 10 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 5 & 10 \\
5 & 5 & 10 & 0 \\
10 & 10 & 0 & 5
\end{array}  \begin{array}{c|ccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
2 & 2 & 0 & 1
\end{array}

and for the product

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\cdot & 0 & 5 & 10 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 0 & 10 & 5 \\
10 & 0 & 5 & 10
\end{array}

\begin{array}{l|lll}
. & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
2 & 0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}

If I choose 0 $\mapsto 0$, $10 \mapsto 1$, because 10 and 1 are units of those rings, respectively and $5 \mapsto 2$, there is no problem to prove that $f(xy)=f(x)f(y)$, but
$$f(5+5)=f(10)=1 \neq 2=1+1=f(5)+f(5)$$

Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: If $5 \mapsto 2$ then $f(5) + f(5) = 1 + 1$ is wrong.

Comment: @aschepler is quite right and the dumb answer I just posted and then deleted is wrong. $10$ is the multiplicative identity in $\Bbb{Z}_{15}$ and you just got the algebra wrong in your attempt to verify whether your proposed mapping is an additive homomorphism.

Comment: Your confusion arises from listing the elements in your $\mathbb{Z}_{15}/5\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ tables in a different order than for $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Comment: @SammyBlack what order is supposed to be? $0\mapsto0$, $5\mapsto1$ and $10\mapsto2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost right.
$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ also holds as
$$f(5+5)=f(10)=1  =2+2=f(5)+f(5)$$

The remaining argument to prove the isomorphism is to note that $f$ has inverse.